# How can I pass a filename with an extention of htm as a string in blazor?

Tags: parameters, blazor

This one might be a bit on the weird side. I want to pass a filename (ex. inmatephone.htm) as a parameter on the URL.  It seems to be successful on the first pass. The link is created like this:

```
<NavLink href="@($"/category/{fileName}")" class="btn btn-primary col-12 my-2">Category List</NavLink>
```

And it works. It recognizes the {fileName} as a parameter and I display it on the page in an input field. The URL looks like this:

```
https://localhost:44302/category/inmatephone.htm
```

The Page is great at this point. However, if I try to revisit, either by just a straight refresh or by Navigation Manager, it claims the page doesn't exist.  I think it might be that the filename has .htm in it. I think the browser is looking for that file and not looking for it as a parameter. It works on that first button above, but a refresh of the page gives me page not found error.

Also, if I try to navigate via:

```
 _navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/category/{fileName}"
```

Again, Page not found.

I think I might be able to solve this by doing something like only passing the file name without the extension and passing an int value as well to tell the component if it is a pdf file or an htm file.  It can only be one of those two. I was hoping someone had seen somethig like this and had a tip.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution above did in fact solve this issue.  I don't think there was any other way.  A refresh of the browser just attempts to locate the .htm or .pdf file.  It is working with the solution I proposed in my original question.